# Why is this only returning 1 row?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query 2 tables with a join. I expect to get 2 rows but only get 1:

```
SELECT tmp.pk, tmp.domain, count(crawl.pk)
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM domains
    WHERE domain IN('www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com')
    AND pk < 10000
) tmp
JOIN crawl ON crawl.domain=tmp.pk
AND crawl.date_crawled <= 3
HAVING COUNT(crawl.pk) < 1000
```

Result:

```
+-------+--------------------+-----------------+
| pk    | domain             | count(crawl.pk) |
+-------+--------------------+-----------------+
| 14929 | www.yahoo.com      |              88 |
+-------+--------------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

If I remove 'www.yahoo.com' from the IN statement then I get 'www.google.com' in the result (therefore, I know that both www.google.com and www.yahoo.com pass my criteria).

Why is it returning only 1 row, when it should be returning 2?

Comment: there is no way to know without seeing the data.

Comment: Where's your `GROUP BY` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why you're using a sub-query. Try this one...

```
SELECT d.pk, d.domain, count(c.pk)
FROM domains d
INNER JOIN crawl c ON d.pk = c.domain
WHERE d.pk < 10000
AND d.domain in ('www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com')
AND c.date_crawled <= 3
GROUP BY d.pk, d.domain
HAVING COUNT(c.pk) < 1000
```

If you're still having issues, I'd try removing the `HAVING` clause as well as the `d.pk < 10000`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make sense because tmp.pk is suppose to be less than 10000 yet your example recordset shows tmp.pk being greater than 10000.

And, your join looks incorrect. Seems you are trying to join a string-based field with a numerical one. I am referring specifically to: `crawl.domain=tmp.pk`

I would suggest you try JOIN by tmp.domain.

Alternatively, I would recommend removing the subquery and restructuring your query to represent more what @Phil suggested in his answer.

Comment: Good point about the pk being too high but this should be a comment, not an answer. I'd also hazard a guess that `crawl.domain` is in fact a foreign key to `domain.pk`

Comment: I understand what you are saying Phil, but considering that both tables contain both a `domain` and a `pk` - I feel it is a strong assumption based on his presented query.

Comment: < 10000 was a mistake on my part in copying the query. Good suggestions. Upvoted.